# Dynamically Populating Dropdown from xhttp.open("Get"); response

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a local text file that I am trying to populate a select dropdown with that data. I have installed IIS to get past the local restrictions and have gotten past CORS. I have used the xhttp method to retrieve the text file data from the file located on the IIS server. I am able to display it in a div as you can see from the below code. I am trying to get this data into a dropdown that I can easily get a value from. For example, if the user selects "Part1" I get an integer value from like 1 as I would from any other dropdown that I specifically declared. I would prefer a javascript solution if possible as that is what the code I have been using for the most part.

I have looked at Google for solutions with nothing really matching.

```
<body onload="pList();">
```

```
<div id="PartList"></div>
```

```
<script>
function pList() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("PartList").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/PartList.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();


}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to split your data into an array and then add to the select this way:

```
<script>
function pList() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var options = this.responseText.split(delimiter);

      var select = document.getElementById("PartList");
      for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.text = options[i];
          option.value = i;
          select.add(option);
      }
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/PartList.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();


}
</script>
```

If you want to clear the select before load use this:

```
document.getElementById("PartList").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: Definitely giving +1 for this. I was able to get this working with \r delimiter. When this is selected, does it return option value as normal? For example I need to know Part1 being first is value 1 ... or 0 whichever applies.

Comment: Check the post again, i modified it with what you want